# Windrose diagram python

Tags: python-3.x, apache-axis, rose-plot

I would need to display both cardinal points and degrees on the same plot in windrose. this is my plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVH2O.png)

My code:

```
ax.bar(df.DIRECCION, df.SPEED,normed=True,opening=0.8,edgecolor='white',bins=6)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok.Thanks for the comment... I generate two diagrams one with degree and one with the cardinal point... Iwold need to have one diagram with cardinal point and degree. I hope I was clearer

Comment: In image in the question Ineed to addesd cardinal points